# How to perform a long press on power button using Accessibility Services

Tags: android

I want to show the turn off/reboot dialog without actually long pressing the power button. Every single source I have found says that this is not possible unless the phone is rooted. However, I found an app called Tasker in the google play store which have the possibility to show the turn off/reboot dialog without the use of the power button or being rooted. This means that it must be possible somehow. The app is using Accessibility Services but I can not figure out how to simulate a long press on the power button. Maybe someone here can help me or point me in the right direction.

I have setup an AccessibilityService which receives events when I press a normal button:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    switch (accessibilityEvent.getEventType()){
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            //What should be here ???
            break;
    }
}
```

This works but I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the global actions triggered by something in your app when you want to show the power dialog.  This could be done by your `Activity` sending an `Intent` to your accessibility service or even a custom binder interface.  Within the service call:

```
performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
```

This requires API 21+, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!